# Can xlsxwriter create an xls file?

Tags: python, xlsxwriter

Is it possible to make a workbook with the `.xls` extension using xlsxwriter?  I used the following code to create a file, but when I open it in Excel I get the message "The file format and extension of 'filename.xls' don't match. The file could be corrupted".  I haven't found an answer in the [docs](http://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.org/).

```
workbook  = xlsxwriter.Workbook('filename.xls')
worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()
worksheet.write(0, 0, 'Hello Excel')
workbook.close()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the introduction page of the docs:

> XlsxWriter is a Python module that can be used to write text, numbers, formulas and hyperlinks to multiple worksheets in an **Excel 2007+ XLSX file**.

It's explicitly stated that this library is for XLS**X** files, not files in the old pre-2007 format.

Further in the [docs](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.org/workbook.html), it says that using the `.xlsx` extension is recommended since Excel may show a warning otherwise. The format of the file xlsxwriter creates is not affected by the extension you give it. Excel sees a mismatch and complains.

> When specifying a filename it is recommended that you use an .xlsx extension or Excel will generate a warning when opening the file.

The docs also list some [alternative packages](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.org/alternatives.html), which may be able to write the XLS format if you really need it.

Answer (score 0):

Your file extension should be *.xlsx*

Comment: OP Specifically asked about using the `.xls` extension.